# Segmentation fault deleting nodes from singly linked list

Tags: c

this is the case i am working on

```
[11] -> [12] -> [13] -> NULL
```

I am trying to delete the elements from the liked list above(example) but I keep getting segfault and on running GDB doesnot help much. I am not looking for an answer but and explanation on where I am going wrong logically.

here is the code

```
int
List:: remove( int val )
{
    ListNode *headNode = _head;
    ListNode *tempNode = NULL;

    if(headNode->_value == val){
        tempNode = headNode->_next;
        delete headNode;
        _head = tempNode;
    }
    else
    {
        while(headNode->_value != val){
            tempNode = headNode;
            headNode = headNode->_next;
        }
        tempNode->_next = headNode->_next;
        delete headNode;

    }
}
```

Comment: do you intend to remove everything with val or the node at val? ordinality vs cardinality...

Comment: @GradyPlayer, so if the value is 12, 12 gets removed from the list and so on.

Comment: This is guaranteed to segfault if (a) the list is empty or (b) you're searching for a value not in the list. Think what happens when you're on the last element, then set `headNode` to `headNode->_next` (presumably NULL), then loop around and look at `headNode->_value`

Comment: Place `while` before `if` and add a condition for value not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not accounting for the following conditions:

- The list may be empty; i.e. `_head` is `NULL`;
- The value may not be in the list at all.
- Your function is declared to return `int`, but makes no such `return`

Assuming the rest of your code is correct (and that is a **big** assumption), I'm all-but-certain this is what you're trying to do:

```
void List::remove( int val )
{
    ListNode *headNode = _head;
    ListNode *tempNode = NULL;

    while (headNode && headNode->_value != val)
    {
        tempNode = headNode;
        headNode = headNode->next;
    }

    if (headNode)
    {
        if (tempNode)
            tempNode->next = headNode->next;
        else
            _head = headNode->next;

        delete headNode;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if so inclined this can get (arguably) simpler utilizing a pointer-to-pointer to traverse the *pointers* in the list, not just their values. It is worth investigating how the following works, which still covers all the bases described previously, but does so using the actual pointers in the list nodes themselves, including `_head`, by-address rather than by-value, thereby eliminating the need for a walk-behind temporary pointer:

```
void List::remove( int val )
{
    ListNode **pp = &_head;

    while (*pp && (*pp)->_value != val)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;

    if (*pp)
    {
        ListNode *p = *pp;
        *pp = p->next;
        delete p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. That's what I wanted to answer but you beat me.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your remove method you are assuming there are always elements in your list.  - What if it is empty?
2. What if the value isn't in the list?  You need to handle this case as well.

---

You're headed in the right direction - there are just a few cases that you haven't considered that can lead you to seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

Example of forward traversal with deletion (forward-only linked list):

```
// Start from the beginning (head), then while the current isn't null, 
// move to the next node.
for (ListNode* current = head; current != null; current = current->next) {

    // Check the next item if there is one, and remove it if it matches the value.
    // We check the next one because you can't delete the current node in a 
    // forward only linked list (can in a doubly-linked list however)
    if (current->_next != nullptr && current->_value == value) {

        // Make this item point to the next next item 
        // (Since we're gonna delete the next item)
        current->_next = current->_next->next;

        // Delete the next item.
        delete current->_next;
     }

}
```

Comment: this line: if (current->_next != nullptr && current->_next = value) has a small error and should be: if (current->_next != nullptr && current->_value = value)  <== check for value match, not 'next' match to 'value'.   BTW:  it is a VERY bad idea to use field/variable names with a leading underscore as they can easily match the compiler generated names.

Comment: Fixed. Also: C++ reserves names beginning with two underscores or an underscore and an uppercase letter, as per ISO C++ 17.4.3.1.2